# Iterating over a dictionary and creating an object for each key with its values within the same object

Tags: python, dictionary, oop

```
import random
import os
import json

class User:
    def _init_(self, username, password, balance):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.balance = balance



def file_read(source):
    with open (source) as file:
        data = file.read()
        dictionary = json.loads(data)
        return dictionary
```

and then the external file is this

```
{"John":["pass123", 2000], "Jenson": ["pass123", 2000]}
```

my initial thought was to use a 
`for items in dict`
but i am unsure how to create multiple objects from that preferably being named by username
thank you.

Comment: what is the output you need for the current input file that you've shown above?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: when i use ``data = file_read(file directory)```

Comment: it will return the dictionary stored in the external file and store it within that variable

Comment: update: got it working now thanks to everyone who helped

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are looking for. Remember it is `__init__` and not `_init_`.

```py
import json

def file_read(source):
    with open(source) as file:
        data = file.read()
        dictionary = json.loads(data)
        return dictionary

class User:
    def __init__(self, username, password, balance):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.balance = balance

    def __str__(self): # String representation of the object for the output.
        return f"{self.username}@{self.password} with balance of {self.balance}"

dictionary = file_read("file.json")

users = []
for key, item in dictionary.items():
    user = User(key, item[0], item[1])
    users.append(user)

# Printing results for output sake.
for user in users:
    print(user)
```

outputs:

```
John@pass123 with balance of 2000
Jenson@pass123 with balance of 2000
```

with `file.json` as:

```
{"John":["pass123", 2000], "Jenson": ["pass123", 2000]}
```

Comment: sorry im just starting out with oop i shall have at the look at the code you have sent and try and implement this thankyou

Comment: No need to be sorry -- we all started somewhere. The second to last `for-loop` is where we are iterating through the items of the dictionary through the use of [`dictionary.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques), and on the line `user = User(key, item[0], item[1])` we are creating our user object.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using a dict comprehension and var-args:

```py
{ k: User(k, *v) for k, v in file_read(filename).items() }
```

Alternatively you can do it with destructuring:

```py
{ k: User(k, pw, bal) for k, (pw, bal) in file_read(filename).items() }
```

Answer (score 0):

What i think you are asking is to create objects for each of the names in the file.

```
class User:
    def __init__(self, username, password, balance):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.balance = balance
def file_read(source):
    with open (source) as file:
       data = file.read()
       dictionary = json.loads(data)
       return dictionary
dicValuesRead = file_read(source)
d = {}
for k,v in dicValuesRead.items():
    d[k] = User(k, v[0], v[1])

print (d)
```

Comment: `file_read` needs to be outside the `class User` for it be callable.

Comment: ah yes editing code on this is hard.. ill fix it thanks

Comment: thank you i shall have a look at dictionary comprehensions

Comment: yes the comprehension is cleaner solution to this.. I like @kaya3 answer below.. Also not as Felipe mentioned youll need to use __init__ in your code..

Answer (score 0):

> preferably being named by username

That is problematic, the most common solution for that part of your question is to create a dictionary of `{username:object}` pairs. See [How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164/how-do-i-create-a-variable-number-of-variables)

Your function returns a dictionary.

- iterate over the [dictionary items](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) which will produce `(name,(password,balance))` tuples
- for each item extract the individual *values*; `name,(password,balance)= item`
- pass those to the class to make a new object and add it to the dictionary
- `new_dict[name] = object`